# Json-Simple , Cast Exception

Tags: java, json, json-simple

please find my code below. When I run this I'm getting `org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray` exception. please help. I'm trying to print all the values inside the JSON

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    URL website = new URL("http://MY_TESTING_SITE");
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;


    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();   

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(response.toString());
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("data"));   //Works fine till here and get proper output

    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");


    Iterator<String> iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }   

}
```

The sample JSON Output looks like the one shown below:

{
    "tsNow": 1376325485,
    "data": {
        "1352": {
            "for_loyal": "1",
            "offer_image": "http://MY_IMAGE.jpg",
            "status": "1",
            "brand_id": "22",
            "id": "1352",
            "brand_image": "http://MY_BRAND_IMAGE.png",
            "title": "Win 20 Family Holidays to USA",
            "description": "Some description ",
            "expiry_date": 1383018300,
            "brand_name": "BRAND NAME",
            "store_locations": [
                {
                    "city_id": "46",
                    "country_id": "9"
                }
                  ]
        }
    },
    "success": true
}

Comment: Can you put some of the JSON you want to extract?

Comment: What's the content of the "data" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the json returned is only an array ie ["asdf", "asdf", "asdf2", "basdf"]
then in java when you parse it with json-simple it will be a JSONArray object

If the json returned is a json object {"key":"value", "keyArray":["asdf","asdf"]}
it will parse to a JSONObject.  If you get the keyArray value it will parse as a JSONArray